# How to map prefetched data to models in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-2.8

Given I've already retrieved a couple of rows as array trough an external service. In a PHP application built on Symfony2 and Doctrine.

How would I go ahead and map that data to models so I can use all existing business logic?

*note: *I don't want to do reflection by myself for private fields nor alter the models.

I tried looking into doctrines internals but a lot seems to be tightly coupled with query logic. And I understand I can implement a factory method to instantiate the model on my set of data, but it feels like I have all classes already in my vendor folder waiting to be utilised.

Comment: Is the [Doctrine Hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md) the "tool" you are looking for?

Comment: That would be exactly what I'm looking for. Is it also available as standalone or with Symfony instead of Zend?

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony you have the [Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html).

You can install it as [standalone component](https://github.com/symfony/serializer) with composer:

`composer require symfony/serializer`

### Serializing an Object

```
$person = new \App\Entity\Person();
$person->setName('foo');
$person->setAge(99);
$person->setSportsman(false);

$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($person, 'json');

// $jsonContent contains {"name":"foo","age":99,"sportsman":false}

echo $jsonContent; // or return it in a Response
```

### Deserializing an Object

```
$person = $serializer->deserialize($jsonContent, \App\Entity\Person::class, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at **Versatile Object Mapper**. It  does exactly what you need by simply adding attributes to your models. It works with private properties and unlike symfony serializer, the structure of your source data does not need to match your models. The models can be Doctrine entities or any other class.

```
composer require zolex/vom
```

**Check the [Quickstart](https://github.com/zolex/vom/blob/master/README.md) and the full [Documentation](https://github.com/zolex/vom/blob/master/docs/README.md)**

Here is an example of a model with the attributes.

```
use Zolex\VOM\Mapping as VOM;

#[VOM\Model]
class MyClass
{
    #[VOM\Property]
    public string $onTheRoot;

    #[VOM\Property(accessor: 'deeper.inThe.structure')]
    public string $fromTheDeep;
}
```

To feed the data in your model:

```
$data = [
    'onTheRoot' => 'I live on the root',
    'deeper' [
        'inThe' => [
            'structure' => 'I live somewhere deeper in the data structure'
        ]
    ]
];

$vom->denormalize($data, MyClass::class);
```